# Innodb + 8K length row limit

Tags: mysql, caching, blob, limit, innodb

I've a Innodb table with, amongst other fields, a blob field that can contain up to ~15KB of data. Reading here and there on the web I found that my blob field can lead (when the overall fields exceed ~8000 bytes) to a split of some records into 2 parts: on one side the record itself with all fields + the leading 768 bytes of my blob, and on another side the remainder of the blob stored into multiple (1-2?) chunks stored as a linked list of memory pages.

So my question: in such cases, what is more efficient regarding the way data is cached by MySQL ? 1) Let the engine deal with the split of my data or 2) Handle the split myself in a second table, storing 1 or 2 records depending on the length of my blob data and having these records cached by MySQL ? (I plan to allocate as much memory as I can for this to occur)

Answer (score 0):

Unless your system's performance is so terrible that you have to take immediate action, you are better off using the internal mechanisms for record splitting.

The people who work on MySQL and its forks (e.g. MariaDB) spend a lot of time implementing and testing optimizations. You will be much happier with simple application code; spend your development and test time on your application's distinctive logic rather than trying to work around internals issues.

Comment: Thanks Ollie. I expect an average 4K-5K online users (of 200K users in DB, each one owns 1 record) generating a request every 5sec, each query reading and/or writing a 15K (max) blob field on his record. I plan to allocate 3 GB of RAM (or more) for the purpose of caching innodb tables. I did it yet for another service but all records are under the 8000 bytes limit and it works like a charm with very good response times. I just wondered if MySQL will use the same caching mechanism with blobs stored outside the record itself. Can someone confirm this ?